# Restructuring my response to supply in my rest api call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably isn't an issue about angularjs but this is giving me a hard time to fix. So I ask here maybe someone can aid me. My problem is to structure the right posted value I got when I submit my form

This is my view.

```
<div ng-repeat="q in entries">
<h4>Question # {{$index+1}}</h4>

<div>
    <labelfor="">Options: </label>
    <a ng-click="addOption($event, $index)">
        <i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add option
    </a><br /><br />
    <div ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
        <label><span>{{opt.id}}.</span></label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="opt.text" placeholder="Add new possible answer here.">
        <a ng-click="q.options.splice($index,1)"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="required_credit">Answer: </label>
    <a ng-click="addAnswer($event, $index)">
        <i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add answer
    </a><br /><br />
 <!-- This is the part where my response got wrong -->
    <div ng-repeat="answer in q.answer">
        <div>
            <select id="city" ng-model="answer.id" ng-options="c.id for c in q.options">
            </select>
            <a ng-click="q.answer.splice($index,1)"><i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

When I submit my form this and console.log the postData, this is what I get:

```
Object {entries: Array[1]}
 entries: Array[1]
  0: Object
   answer: Array[1]
    0: Object
     id: Object
      id: ""
      text: ""
     text: ""
```

This is what I expect to supply in my rest api post:

```
Object {entries: Array[1]}
 entries: Array[1]
  0: Object
   answer: Array[1]
    0: Object
     id: "a"
     text: "Homer Simpson"
```

Notice the difference between the entries.answer property, that where i'm stuck on. T__T.

Comment: I read this twice and still have no idea what your question is. No wonder you're having hard time fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
 <select id="city" ng-model="answer.id" ng-options="c.id for c in q.options">
            </select>
```

should be

```
 <select id="city" ng-model="answer.id" ng-options="c.id as c.id for c in q.options">
            </select>
```

Comment: gave me an error: Error: Expected ngOptions in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'c.id for c.id in q.options'.

Comment: @WonderingCoder i have fixed the expression please check.

Comment: I was able to get the correct structure of my postData, but I'm only getting the id value, I would also need to add the value of the "c.text" and pass it to my controller. If I changed ng-options="c.text .." then I would only get the text, how do I get both, the id and the text of c object?

Comment: With your earlier expression you were getting text and id, but that was causing issue with you post data. You can take the selected value into some other variable and manually assign answer.id to the it of that selected element.

Comment: sorry, I hardcoded the earlier response to make it understandable of my situation. But from the very start I can only assign only one value either id or text not both. Do you mean I could put a hidden field and assign the text or id there?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You don't need any hidden, how you keep what is selected depends upon your model. What you send to server and what is shown or binded to UI does differ, and you have to manually map that data.